# Force Jackson Backreference to be resolved first

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a JSON object tree like this:

```
{
    "name": "parent",
    "children": [
        {
            "name":"child",
            "value":5
        }
    ]
}
```

In Java the parent class has a list of children marked with `@JsonManagedReference` and the child class has a corresponding `@JsonBackReference`. My problem is that the setter method of the `value` property depends on the parent. Sadly in all my experiments the back reference is resolved last and thus the parent field in the child object is still null when the value is set. Is there a way to change this deserialization order? Or is there another way to solve this elegantly without introducing unnecessary fields.

```
public class Parent {
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Child> children;
    private String name;

    //getter/setter

    public int doStuff(int input) {
        return 0; //complex calculations here
    }
}

public class Child{
    @JsonBackReference
    private Parent parent;
    private String name;
    private int value;

    //getter/setter

    public void setValue(int v) {
        this.value = getParent().doStuff(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?